# Appropriate Feature Selection model for Mass Spectrometry data

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, filter

I have a cancer patients data which consists of more than half million features and my task is to apply feature selection algorithm to extract the most relevant features from it. My question is which feature selection model would me more appropriate in this case... Any suggestions will be more appreciated...

Comment: Can you describe what makes Mass spectrometry data different from other datasets to narrow down your question? At the moment, the answer is "Google", e.g.: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/12/introduction-to-feature-selection-methods-with-an-example-or-how-to-select-the-right-variables/

Comment: @JanKukacka Mass spectrometry datasets contains more features than samples and normally used in the medical background

Comment: You don't need to tell me, I am only trying to help you improving your question to be able to attract any answers. Just add this information into the question text. Also, it might be helpful to write what you want to do with the data after the feature selection: for every problem, different features may be useful.